# How to force Log4j write into new file when existing one is renamed

Tags: log4j

I have Java application that uses Log4j 1.2.17 and works under Debian system. I use Linux logrolling engine to periodically rename log files. But, Log4j continue to write into renamed file but not creates new one to write into. (Perhaps it keeps the file descriptor). 
My question is the following: how extend log4j to adding such new functionality - writing to the new file when existing one is renamed.

Thank you,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I have found the alternate solution. I have prepared the thread that periodically checks the existence of original log file (e.g. every 1 min). As soon as it absent, the thread reconfigures the appender so that it will create and use the originally defined file for logging.
I use the following method for mentioned above action.

```
    protected void checkLogFile(){
        Enumeration<?> e = Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            Appender appender = (Appender) e.nextElement();
            if (FileAppender.class.isInstance(appender)) {
                FileAppender fa = (FileAppender) appender;
                String fileName = fa.getFile();
                File logFile = new File(fileName).getAbsoluteFile();
                logger.debug("check logFile = " + logFile);
                if (!logFile.exists()) {
                    logger.debug("logFile is not exist. create a new log file: " + fileName);
                    fa.setFile(fileName);
                    fa.activateOptions();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please note that the original log file is defined in the log4j config by relative path (e.g. '../log/proc.log')